# ID replace and new ID use for further process in Jquery

Tags: jquery

On "click" I am changing ID of `myDiv` to `myDiv1`.  Now I want to use new ID (`myDiv1`) which replaced `myDiv`.

```
$("#myDiv").attr('id', 'myDiv1');
```

but I can't further manipulation with `myDiv1` like:

```
$("#myDiv1").mouseover(function() {
    $('#bottom_link').show(400);
});
```

Comment: Not enough information. Please create a http://jsfiddle.net demo.

Comment: IMO changing the ID of a DOM element is pretty sketchy; why are you doing that?

Comment: I did a demo for him and it works fine http://jsfiddle.net/xTzrz/

Comment: Did you try to bind the `mouseover` event to `#myDiv1` before you changed the ID?

Comment: Why are you changing the ID?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: you should realy accept one of these answers, or atleast tell us if they don't work?

Answer (score 2):

A better way (IMO) to do this would be:

```
var myDiv = $("#myDiv");
```

This caches the div as a jQuery object, so you can manipulate it all you like and still be able to do things with it without having to select it again.

Eg:

```
myDiv.attr("id", "someOtherId");
myDiv.css("background-color", "orange");
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/DWeSL/

Edit:

You can then also bind events to this like:

```
myDiv.click(function(){
  alert("boo");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Not that I agree with changing IDs dynamically, but your problem may be that you are trying to attach event handlers to the element before it exists under the new ID. Try using [jQuery's delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) to attach the event instead.

Edit: adding some code as $.delegate is not the friendliest function to learn...

```
$.delegate('#myDiv1', 'mouseover', function() {
    $('#bottom_link').show(400);
});
```

This will ensure that any element with the ID "myDiv1" that exists now or any time in the future will have this event handler bound to it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of selecting your div by its id select it by classname. You would do

```
<div = "myDiv" class="myDiv"></div>

$(".myDiv").mouseover(function() {
......your code here.......
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
  $("#myDiv").text('Test1');
  $("#myDiv").attr('id', 'myDiv1');
  $("#myDiv1").text('Test2');
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myDiv">Test</div>
</body>
</html>
```